# Sending a single file to multiple machines using a list using bash script

Tags: linux, bash

First things first: Thank you all for jumping in and providing your knowledge where mine is lacking greatly. So, I took the advice of David C. Rankin and tried to rewrite what he provided here and I ran into some problems.

This the terminal output I received when I tried to run the new code. All the permissions are correct and I have other scripts I can still execute.

```
[root@srvr-5 ~]# ls -al wakupMAC.sh 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 2816 Oct  3 11:33 wakupMAC.sh
[root@srvr-5 ~]# 
[root@srvr-5 ~]# ./wakupMAC.sh 
bash: ./wakupMAC.sh: /bin.bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
[root@srvr-5 ~]#
```

And this is the code that I replaced mine with. It should be a duplicate of David's (mostly) but something is wrong and I don't know what it is. I actually have 109 machines in the array to choose from but reduced it down here for size sake. So what did I mess up?

```
#!/bin.bash
#wakeupMAC.sh
#Written Oct 3, 2014

#Array of 109 machine MAC addresses to wake up
WS=( E4:11:5B:31:25:22 
00:1c:23:47:5a:14 
00:1c:23:50:1a:c6 
00:1c:23:4a:d9:67 
00:1c:23:4b:2b:ad )

if [ "$1" = "-a" ] || [ "$1" = "--all" ]; then #Corrected
   for i in ${WS[@]}; do
      /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 "$i"
     printf " called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 %s\n" "$i"
   done
   exit 0
fi

#Create prompt and a menu for selectable launch
PS3='Selection: '
while [ ! $name ]; do
   printf "\nSelect the WS number from the following menu to launch:\n\n"
   select name in ${WS[@]} All quit; do
      if [ "$name" = "All" ]; then
         for i in ${WS[@]}; do
            /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 "$i"
            printf " called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 %s\n" "$i"
         done
         break
      elif [ "$name" = "quit" ]; then
         break
      else
         /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 "$name"
    printf " called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 %s\n" "$name"
      fi
   done
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks mso, Matthias is correct, so when I entered your code it didn't give me the ability to choose which machines from the ARRAY I wanted to wake up. I goofed up my original purpose. So let me try again, hopefully better, "I" want to select which machines to wake up. Not neccesarily in order, but deliberatly chosen by me, not randomly chosen by the script. I super appreciate the responses and I will get better at asking my questions. I am new at this and am not a coder (yet) and do not have one here so I am trying to muddle through making things easier to adminstratively manage.

Comment: In the line: `if [ "$1" - "-a" ] || [ "$1" = "--all" ]; then` Look at the first test. The `-` should be an `=` (that will throw and error) The rest looks OK. Drop a comment if you have any more issues. You should also quote `"${WS[@]}"` in `select name in ${WS[@]} All quit; do` (not needed with macs, but anything with spaces will require it).

Comment: David, I did fix the = issue right after i posted this and that made no difference in the output (still same as listed above). Missed the " ". Will search that one and see what happens.

Comment: Also, when I couldn't get the error corrected (terminal output listed above) I copied and pasted the entire code into a .sh file with 755 permissions and still received the same terminal error output.

Answer (score 0):

Adding following code should work:

```
ARRAY=(E4:11:5B:31:78:1D   E4:11:5B:31:25:22     E4:11:5B:3B:60:4C       E4:11:5B:3A:6E:21      E4:11:5B:31:D5:2A       E4:11:5B:31:D6:61 )

echo 'List of machines: '
echo "E4:11:5B:31:78:1D   E4:11:5B:31:25:22     E4:11:5B:3B:60:4C       E4:11:5B:3A:6E:21      E4:11:5B:31:D5:2A       E4:11:5B:31:D6:61 "
echo 'Enter number of machine to wake up (0-5): '

read input1
echo "Waking up: " ${ARRAY[$(($input1))]}
#/sbin/ether-wake -i eth0  ${ARRAY[$(($input1))]}   # uncomment this to test

exit
```

Comment: I am not sure but how i understand the op *he* wants to select randomly and not the script, but i may be mistaking...

Comment: I have corrected the code for you to enter machine number to wake up.

Comment: Yesterday, before I posted this question I looked on this site, on LINUX forums (3 of them), and I could not find any question that addressed my fix for this script. The closest one I found dealt with menus. Which would be good but cumbersome I think.

Comment: You can loop above code to wake up multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

Using the bash `select menu` feature provides a clean solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

## array of machine mac addresses
macs=(  E4:11:5B:31:78:1D        
        E4:11:5B:31:25:22        
        E4:11:5B:3B:60:4C        
        E4:11:5B:3A:6E:21        
        E4:11:5B:31:D5:2A        
        E4:11:5B:31:D6:61 )

## accept -a or --all to wake all without menu
if [ "$1" = "-a" ] || [ "$1" = "--all" ]; then
    for i in ${macs[@]}; do
        /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 "$i"
        printf "  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 %s\n" "$i"
    done
    exit 0
fi

## set prompt for select menu
PS3='Selection: '

## create a select menu allowing individual or all to be awaken
while [ ! $name ]; do 
    printf "\nSelect the computer from the following menu:\n\n"
    select name in ${macs[@]} All quit; do 
        if [ "$name" = "All" ]; then
            for i in ${macs[@]}; do
                /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 "$i"
                printf "  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 %s\n" "$i"
            done
            break
        elif  [ "$name" = "quit" ]; then
            break
        else
            /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 "$name"
            printf "  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 %s\n" "$name"
        fi
    done
done

exit 0
```

**output:**

**Selecting Individual Machines:**

```
$ bash selectmac.sh

Select the computer from the following menu:

1) E4:11:5B:31:78:1D  4) E4:11:5B:3A:6E:21  7) All
2) E4:11:5B:31:25:22  5) E4:11:5B:31:D5:2A  8) quit
3) E4:11:5B:3B:60:4C  6) E4:11:5B:31:D6:61
Selection: 4
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:3A:6E:21
Selection: 6
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:31:D6:61
Selection: 8
```

**Selecting All Machines:**

```
$ bash selectmac.sh

Select the computer from the following menu:

1) E4:11:5B:31:78:1D  4) E4:11:5B:3A:6E:21  7) All
2) E4:11:5B:31:25:22  5) E4:11:5B:31:D5:2A  8) quit
3) E4:11:5B:3B:60:4C  6) E4:11:5B:31:D6:61
Selection: 7
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:31:78:1D
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:31:25:22
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:3B:60:4C
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:3A:6E:21
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:31:D5:2A
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:31:D6:61
```

**Waking all from command line:**

```
$ bash selectmac.sh -a
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:31:78:1D
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:31:25:22
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:3B:60:4C
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:3A:6E:21
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:31:D5:2A
  called -> /sbin/ether-wake -i eth0 E4:11:5B:31:D6:61
```

Comment: Looked like this could/should replace my code completely. So that is what I did and ran into some problems. I'll post them so everyone can take a look at what I did and tell me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, esp. you David Rankin, it works. A simple sytax error was keeping it from working.

> ## !/bin.bash

I fixed the dot(.) to the proper slash(/) syntax, `#!/bin/bash`, and it works like it should. Rookie mistake I know.

It just took time to keep looking over the code to find where the error was. I knew it had to be something simple like a space or a dash or an equal where it shouldn't be.

But the error

> [root@srvr-5 ~]# ./wakupMAC.sh  bash: ./wakupMAC.sh: /bin.bash: bad
>   interpreter: No such file or directory

kept telling me that it wasn't in the body of the code. Which lead me to copying and pasting in

```
#!/bin/bash
ERROR=165
```

from another script. After it worked I looked closely at what the difference was and discovered the syntax error.

I can now selectively wake up whatever machine I want on my network of 100+ machines.